# Closed form for double integral?

Tags: integral-transforms

I have the following double integral:
$\int\limits_0^x {\int\limits_0^y {{e^{ - {K_1}(u + v)}}{I_0}\left( {2{K_1}\sqrt {uv} } \right)dudv} }$
where $K_1$ is a constant. Do you have any ideas of getting a closed form for this integral? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the function $I_0$? You can get rid of the constant by substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution from a reference paper, which is: A Double Integral Containing the Modified Bessel Function: Asymptotics and Computation.

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-47-176/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To Jochen Wengenroth, my guess is I_{0} is a modified Bessel function.
To the OP.
 I have no expertise when it comes to this, but if it is a Bessel function, converting it to some polar form of some kind might help.

Comment: I found the solution from a reference paper, which is: A Double Integral Containing the Modified Bessel Function: Asymptotics and Computation. 

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a link to the paper unknown (google) cited:  http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-47-176/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X.pdf

Comment: @Binh Nguyen: Please, post this as an answer and accept it, so that the software does not bump the question periodically thinking it is unanswered.